# Redirect stdin from exec to reading pipe

Tags: c, pipe, fork, stdin, xargs

Basically I'm programming my own xargs implementation for practicing. The main difference with the original xargs is that what I do is to buffer the first 4 lines I get from stdin in the parent process and write it in the pipe I created, so it processes 4 lines at a time instead of each line. Then, in the child process I redirect stdin to the reading pipe so when I call exec it should receive the arguments. After that, when child ends, the parent should do this again until all stdin was read.

So let's say I do `cat directories.txt | ./my_xargs ls` where directories is a file that has:

```
/var/
/opt/
/dev/
```

I should get the result of running `ls /var/ /opt/ /dev/`. But instead I'm getting as if I've run just `ls` without parameters.

I tried several things:

- Writing a file and redirecting that file descriptor to stdin. Didn't work.
- I already checked the pipe is written correctly debugging and also printing the result of reading the pipe instead of calling exec.
- closing stdin and opening a new file and write what I read in the child to that file. When I debug I can even see that that file descriptor is 0.
- removing the line `close(pd[0]);` didn't work either.

```
    #ifndef NARGS
    #define NARGS 4
    #endif
    
    #define LINE_SIZE 1024
    #define PATH_MAX 1024
    
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    
    typedef enum { false, true } bool;
    
    int
    main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        bool eof = false;
        int pd[2];
    
        size_t len = 0;
        
    
        while (!eof) {
    
            if (pipe(pd) == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pipe\n");
            }
            pid_t pid;
            pid = fork();
            if (pid == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Fork error\n");
            }
            if (pid == 0) {          // child
                close(pd[1]);    // child doesn't write
                dup2(pd[0], 0); // changing reading pipe por stdin
                close(pd[0]);
                execvp(argv[1], argv + 1);
    
                perror("Exec failed.\n");
            } else {
                close(pd[0]);  // parent doesn't read
    
                char total_params[PATH_MAX] = "";
                char* newLine = NULL;
    
                int i = 0;
                while (i < NARGS && !eof) {
                    // Reading stdin
                    eof = getline(&newLine, &len, stdin) < 1;
                    // Removing '\n'
                    if ( i+1 < NARGS) {
                        newLine[strcspn(newLine, "\n")] = ' ';
                    } else {
                        newLine[strcspn(newLine, "\n")] = '\0';
                    }
                    strcat(total_params, newLine);  
                    i++;
                }
                free(newLine);
                write(pd[1], &total_params, strlen(total_params));
                close(pd[1]);
                wait(NULL);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `xargs` is supposed to convert its input to command line arguments, not copy it to the target program's input. You should not need to create a pipe for anything.

Comment: @CarlNorum I know I don't need to. I'm doing it to learn/practice how to direct any input to stdin

Comment: Yeah I'm saying you're not implementing `xargs`. `ls` can't do anything with the input you're giving it. If you want to implement something else, that's fine, you just can't expect it to work like `xargs`.

Comment: `trcat(total_params, newLine);` <<-- total_params could be a bit too small here ...

Comment: @CarlNorum if you run `cat directories.txt | xargs ls` it runs ls with every line of directories.txt as a parameter for ls. I tested it.

Comment: Yes. That is what xargs does. It is not what your program does, or even tries to do. That's what I'm trying to say. `xargs` copies its input to become the arguments of the program you give to it (in your case, `ls`). Your program apparently copies its input into a pipe hooked up to the input of the target program. Those aren't the same thing.

Comment: @CarlNorum oooh I see what you're saying now! you're saying I have to convert the input to a parameter because ls won't read from its stdin, and it's xargs responsability to do that. right?

Comment: @wildplasser thanks, this is not the case but I might have another bug there waiting for me haha. But at least with the tests I did the stdin input is arriving ok to the pipe when reading.

Comment: Yes - that was what I was trying to get at. `xargs` is the utility that does that conversion.